# Help Understanding Field Extension/Linear Algebra Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $E = F(\alpha)$ be a simple field extension of a finite field F by an algebraic element $\alpha$. Thinking of $E$ as an $F$-vector space, define a linear transformation $$T:E\rightarrow E\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x\mapsto \alpha \cdot x$$ Show that this transformation has no non-trivial invariant subspaces.

Suppose $U$ is a proper $T$-invariant subspace of $E$. If we define $S$ to be $T|_U$, I know that an important step in the solution is the fact that the minimal polynomial of $S$ divides the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

The thing is, I don't know why this is true. What does the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ have to do with the minimal polynomials of transformations on $E=F(\alpha)$?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you know that from? What book/paper are you reading this stuff from?

Comment: Our professor solved the problem in class.

Comment: Ok then: how did he prove/justify that the min. pol. of $\;S\;$ (an operator) divides the min. pol. of $\;\alpha\;$ (an algebraic element over $\;\Bbb F\;$ )?

Comment: As far as I know, we never explicitly covered that fact. We got into minimal polynomials of operators after having covered extension fields, and the relationship between the two kinds of minimal polynomial was not really discussed.

Comment: So he just "mentioned" it, or how do you know it is/it must be, true?

Comment: I'm assuming that what he says is correct. He wrote that $\mu_S | x^d + b_{d-1}x^{d-1} + ...$. There is a small possibility that I'm misinterpreting what he said, but I copied down what he wrote verbatim. I believe $d$ here is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ have degree $n$, and let $b\ne0$ be in the invariant subspace $U$. Then $ab,a^2b,\dots,a^{n-1}b$ are also in the subspace. No linear combination of the $n$ elements $b,ab,\dots,a^{n-1}b$ can vanish; if it did, you'd have a polynomial of degree $n-1$ vanishing at $a$, contrary to degree of $a$ being $n$. So the dimension of $U$ is $n$, so $U$ is not a proper subspace.